# Does magento 2.3.6 supports Klarna On site Messaging?

Tags: magento2.3.6, klarna

I want to know whether Klarna OSM supports 2.3.6 or not I have tried to add the scripts as per the documentation of Klarna but it's not working. After that, I have checked Magento's official documentation and it does not have any settings but for 2.4.0 onwards it has. Please let me know is it possible to implement it in 2.3.6 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2.4 supports Klarna On-Site Messaging out of the box. In M2.3.6 you will have to do much enough customizations for this. And probably it would be more reasonable to update Magento instead.

Here are Magento docs if needed: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/klarna-setup.html#step-2-enable-klarna-on-site-messaging-optional